# Why is nginx container redirecting my private domain to a different location?

Tags: docker, nginx, transmission, plex

I kind of avoided using Nginx because it didn't match my needs across the years. But now, I find myself forced to start using it.

**Goal**: to have a private "ho.me" domain and with it, to go to my 2 containers:

1. /t to my Transmission server container (192.168.50.30:9091);
2. /tv to my Plex media server container (192.168.50.30:32400/web).

**Issue:** "ho.me" forwards me to where also /t does but I want "ho.me" to just show my static index.html and not take me to the Transmission server. What am I doing wrong?

In this raw phase, I'm using a Bash script, a Dockerfile and 2 .conf files. In order to create and run the nginx container I'm running these files in this order:

1. configure_and_run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Goal: configure all files and run the nginx-reverse-proxy container
#1. Update system
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
#2. Get rid of unnecesary remaining software
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge
#3. Create a folder that holds the configuration for ho.me VirtualHost
sudo mkdir /apps/docker/apacheconf/sites
#4. Copy the initial ho.me VirtualHost home.conf file
sudo cp -r home.conf /apps/docker/apacheconf/sites/
#5.  Create a folder that holds the html files of the web server
sudo mkdir /apps/docker/apacheconf/htmlfiles
#6. Copy the initial index.html so we can test it works
sudo cp -r index.html /apps/docker/apacheconf/htmlfiles/
#Build the nginx-reverse-proxy via the existing
docker build -t nginx-reverse-proxy .
#Run the container 
docker container run \
--publish 80:80 \
-d --name nginxrp \
-v /apps/docker/apacheconf/sites:/usr/local/apache2/conf/sites \
-v /apps/docker/apacheconf/htmlfiles:/usr/local/apache2/home \
nginx-reverse-proxy
```

2. home.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ho.me
    ServerAlias ho.me
    ServerAdmin admin@home.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/home
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/home">
        Order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    SSLProxyEngine on
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto “https”
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port “443”    
    ErrorLog logs/home-error.log
    CustomLog logs/home-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

4. default.conf:

```
# Complete Nginx Docker reverse proxy config file
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

# The Transmission torrent client redirection
  location /t {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.50.30:9091;
  }
 # The Plex media server redirection 
location /tv/ {
    rewrite /tv(/.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.50.30:32400;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    sub_filter '/web/' '/tv/web/';
    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter_once off;
}
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
} 
}
```

3. simple Docker file:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing curly brace on the `/` location in your nginx configuration.

Comment: Damn, that was so stupid! Thank you, [@HansKilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: [@HansKilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) noticed I was missing a closing curly brace on the "/" location in my nginx config.